# Custom view with TextView and EditText doesn't work with android:fastForward

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view, custom-view

I created a custom view that has the following layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hintTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintTextInputText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="hint"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hintTextInputInputIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hint_text_input_input_icon_margin_end"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_eyeopen"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/hintTextInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hintTextInputEditText"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintTextInputPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hint_text_input_input_placeholder_margin_end"
        tools:text="placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/hintTextInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/hintTextInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/hintTextInputInputIcon"/>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/hintTextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/hintTextInputInputIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hintTextInputText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hint_text_input_input_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hint_text_input_input_margin_end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        tools:text="edit"/
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also I defined the view in attrs.xml file:

```
<declare-styleable name="HintTextInputView">
    <attr name="hint_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="input_text_size" format="dimension"/>

    <attr name="hint_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="input_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="input_hint_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="android:text"/>
    <attr name="android:nextFocusForward"/>

    <attr name="hint_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="input_hint_text" format="string"/>

    <attr name="hint_text_style" format="enum">
        <enum name="normal" value="0"/>
        <enum name="bold" value="1"/>
        <enum name="italic" value="2"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="input_text_style" format="enum">
        <enum name="normal" value="0"/>
        <enum name="bold" value="1"/>
        <enum name="italic" value="2"/>
    </attr>

    <attr name="enable_input_icon" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="input_icon_enabled_image" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="input_icon_disabled_image" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="input_icon_tint_color" format="color"/>

    <attr name="enable_borders" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="border_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="focused_border_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="border_radius" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="android:inputType"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I'm also setting the attributes programmatically to the EdditText when they're defined at any layout:

```
private fun TextView.setFocusForward(attributes: TypedArray) {
    attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.HintTextInputView_android_nextFocusForward, 0).let {
        if (it != 0) {
            this.nextFocusForwardId = it
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the XML that has the views looks like:

```
<br.sis.smb.base.ui.HintTextInputView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    style="@style/DefaultEditTextBorder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/register_company_margin_start_end"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/register_company_edittext_top_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/register_company_margin_space_between"
    android:text="@={viewModel.name}"
    android:nextFocusForward="@id/firstNickname"
    app:hint_text="@string/register_edittext_name_hint"
    app:input_hint_text="@string/register_edittext_name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/firstNickname"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
/>

<br.sis.smb.base.ui.HintTextInputView
    android:id="@+id/firstNickname"
    style="@style/DefaultEditTextBorder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/register_company_margin_space_between"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/register_company_margin_start_end"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/secondNickname"
    android:text="@={viewModel.nickname}"
    app:hint_text="@string/register_edittext_nickname_first"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4"
/>
```

The problem is that the attribute android:nextFocusForward doesn't work at all. Even though I defined like above code, when I touch on next on my device's keyboard it doesn't lead to the right custom view but to the below custom view.

[image]

Comment: are you running on emulator

Comment: @ManojPerumarath yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're not running on an emulator and on some emulator's `nextfocusforward` won't work, in that case you've to use `nextFocusDown`.

> Also singleLine= true should be there and imeOptions =actionNext

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not been setting `inputType:'none'` or `'0x00000000'`